# Flexslider caption move upwards instead of fade

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, flexslider

Is there any way I can move like here: http://ssdigitalmedia.com/
using flex slider on my other site I am using flex slider but flex caption or not working as abve links text are moving ..is there any way I can do with flex or should I go for any other slider?

Thanks
Sudhanshu

Comment: I assume you are not asking a question about Adobe/Apache Flex; so I removed the Flex tag.

Answer (score 1):

Flex slider is just slider, you need parallax effect solution.

Check this one

http://nick-jonas.github.io/windows/